# Blackberry: InCall Screen

Tags: blackberry

I want to show my screen during the incoming call.
Is there is any way to override the InCall Screen in Blackberry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of PhoneListener  interface and then override the methods to do the same.

```
public class CatchCall extends Application implements PhoneListener {

    boolean yes = false;
    int st;

    public CatchCall() {
        Phone.addPhoneListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CatchCall().enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public void callAdded(int callId) {
    }

    public void callAnswered(int callId) {
    }

    public void callConferenceCallEstablished(int callId) {
    }

    public void callConnected(int callId) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method s
        PhoneCall phoneCall = Phone.getCall(callId);
        if (phoneCall != null) {               
                //TODO: push your screen here
                Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_YES_NO, "Push my screen here");
        }
    }

    public void callDirectConnectConnected(int callId) {
    }

    public void callDirectConnectDisconnected(int callId) {
    }

    public void callDisconnected(int callId) {

    }

    public void callEndedByUser(int callId) {
    }

    public void callFailed(int callId, int reason) {
    }

    public void callHeld(int callId) {
    }

    public void callIncoming(int callId) {
                //TODO: push your screen here
        Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_YES_NO, "Push my screen here");

    }

    public void callInitiated(int callid) {

        PhoneCall phoneCall = Phone.getCall(callid);
        if (phoneCall != null) {
                //TODO: push your screen here
           Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_YES_NO, "Push my screen here");
         }

    }

    public void callRemoved(int callId) {
    }

    public void callResumed(int callId) {
    }

    public void callWaiting(int callid) {
    }

    public void conferenceCallDisconnected(int callId) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is i require to push my screen in three call back methods... Is it is not sufficient to push it only on callIncoming() method.

Comment: Can you explain these things in the original question. It would help us to help you.